# Does this equation satisfy Lipschitz condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does this equation satisfy Lipschitz condition?

$y'=\frac{1+t}{1+y}$

Its solution is given, but I want to know if it satisfies Lipschitz condition. I worked on that but I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the condition to apply the Cauchy-Lipschitz or Picard-Lindelöf theorem, then it is
$$|f(t, y_1) - f(t, y_2)|\le C |y_1- y_2|$$
where
$$f(t, y) = \frac{1+t}{1+y}$$
This will be true in any bounded domain where $y$ stays away from $-1$ because $f$ has a continuous derivative with respect to $y$. In fact, if
$\alpha>0$ and $\beta> 0$ and $|1+y|\ge \alpha$ and $|1+t|\le \beta$, then

$$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t, y)\right|=
\left|-\frac{1+t}{(1+y)^2}\right| \le \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2} $$
it follows that if $y_1, y_2\ge -1+\alpha$ or $y_1, y_2\le -1-\alpha$ and
$t\in [-1-\beta, -1+\beta]$, one has
$$
|f(t, y_1) - f(t, y_2)|\le\frac{\beta}{\alpha^2}|y_1 - y_2|
$$
As a consequence, given $(t_0, y_0)\in U = {\mathbb R}\times({\mathbb R\setminus \{-1\}})$, there is a unique maximal solution $y(t)$ such that $y(t_0) = y_0$ and for all $t$, $(t, y(t))\in U$.

Comment: That is my point. In this question they don’t give any conditions on y. In addition, I have to find a specific value of C if the equation satisfies Lipschitz condition.